# How can I configure my docker-compose for connect my 'app' running in docker containner to my 'database' running in physical machine

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, gateway

```
version: '3'
services:
   my_app:
     build: ./api
     environments:
       - DB_HOST=192.168.10.1 #Physical IP database server
```

> Docker Engine Server IP: 192.168.20.1

Comment: ...it looks like you might have clarified, in a comment on an answer, that the database is on a different machine?  Broadly, the setup you've shown here should work (use the database's DNS name or IP address as normal).  A [mcve] including the actual error message would help clarify what's going on; definitely clarify if the database isn't on the same machine, since that's the case people frequently ask about.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
network_mode: host
```

to my_app, and use localhost

https://forums.docker.com/t/option-network-mode-host-in-docker-compose-file-not-working-as-expected/51682

Comment: I don't need to connect to my localhost, i need to connect to other physical machine in the same network tith my localhost. 
And i think i need a bridge driver cause my app connect also with others docker containers

Comment: https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2014-08-11-four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/ It might help you

Comment: Host networking generally disables Docker's networking stack, and things like inter-container communication won't work well.  I'd use one of the other solutions described in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).